# poor reading performance of SSD drive

Tags: ssd, hardware-failure, nvme

I have two SSD (nvme, pcie 4.0) and one SATA disk. One of the SSD seems to be very slow in reading operations - one is getting 2 GB/s and the other one 200 MB/s. 
I'm not sure what can be the cause or how can I get more info. Any ideas?

Benchmark:

```
root:/# hdparm -Tt /dev/nvme0n1; echo 'second'; hdparm -Tt /dev/nvme1n1

/dev/nvme0n1:
 Timing cached reads:   29588 MB in  2.00 seconds = 14813.35 MB/sec
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
 Timing buffered disk reads: 596 MB in  3.01 seconds = 198.00 MB/sec
second

/dev/nvme1n1:
 Timing cached reads:   29354 MB in  2.00 seconds = 14697.06 MB/sec
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
 Timing buffered disk reads: 6376 MB in  3.00 seconds = 2124.77 MB/sec
```

I havent found any issue running `smartctl -a /dev/nvme0` or `nvme error-log /dev/nvme0`

System details:

```
root:/# uname -a
Linux ryzen-desktop 5.11.0-25-generic #27~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 13 17:41:23 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root:/# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS \n \l
```

Slow SSD is 74% full:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1  916G  638G  232G  74% /other
```

HW specification:

Motherboard: X570 AORUS MASTER (https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/X570-AORUS-MASTER-rev-10/sp#sp, manual (pdf) - https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_x570-aorus-master_1002_e.pdf?v=30c7ecc8f9bc0e464b65a4062dd58841)

First SSD (fast): Force Series Gen.4 PCIe MP600 1TB NVMe M.2 SSD (https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Storage/M-2-SSDs/Force-Series%E2%84%A2-Gen-4-PCIe-NVMe-M-2-SSD/p/CSSD-F1000GBMP600)

Second SSD (slow): WD BLACK SN850 NVMe SSD (https://www.westerndigital.com/products/internal-drives/wd-black-sn850-nvme-ssd#WDS100T1X0E)

I have also old SATA HDD connected.

Corsair (the fast one) is connected to M2C and WD (slow one) to M2A slots (see the motherboard's manual). The SATA disk is connected to SATA port 1.

Comment: It more looks like Corsair issue but for test you may want to extract any other drives and test it separately. Also make sure PCIe slots are working in the same mode. You may want to swap devices in the slots.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this was caused by the firmware of WD SSD disk. I needed to update to the latest one and then I got the claimed speed again.
https://www.pcgamer.com/wd-is-fixing-a-bug-that-makes-black-sn850-ssds-run-slow-on-x570-motherboards/